# MS SQL using WHERE condition from another Table

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I need to create a database over a "Whist card game". In every game there are 4 players and there can be 1-3 winners per game. A winner gets 10% of the loser's point.
So far, I have created 3 tables and filled them with the data, but now I need to create the Transaction which calculates the points.
Here is what I got so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Players
(  
    ID          INT         IDENTITY(1,1)   Primary key,
    Name        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,  
    Point       INT         NOT NULL,
    NewPoint    INT
);

CREATE TABLE Runde
(
   ID       INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary key,
   Player1  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID)  NOT NULL,
   Player2  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID)  NOT NULL,
   Player3  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID)  NOT NULL,
   Player4  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID)  NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Result
(
   ID           INT IDENTITY(1,1) Primary key,
   RundeID      INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Runde(ID)    NOT NULL,
   PlayerID     INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Players(ID)  NOT NULL,
   Winder       BIT NOT NULL
);

insert into Players (Name, Point) values ('Anne',       1000);
insert into Players (Name, Point) values ('Bettina',    1000);
insert into Players (Name, Point) values ('Charlotte ', 1000);
insert into Players (Name, Point) values ('Dorte ',     1000);
insert into Players (Name, Point) values ('Erik ',      1000);
insert into Players (Name, Point) values ('Frederik ',  1000);
insert into Players (Name, Point) values ('Gunnar ',    1000);
insert into Players (Name, Point) values ('Helge ',     1000);
Insert into Runde   (Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4) values (1, 2, 3, 4);
Insert into Runde   (Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4) values (5, 6, 7, 8);

--gamewhere Anne og Bettina winds

Insert into Result  (RundeID, PlayerID, Winder) values (1, 1, 1);
Insert into Result  (RundeID, PlayerID, Winder) values (1, 2, 1);
Insert into Result  (RundeID, PlayerID, Winder) values (1, 3, 0);
Insert into Result  (RundeID, PlayerID, Winder) values (1, 4, 0);

--game where Erik winds

Insert into Result  (RundeID, PlayerID, Winder) values (2, 5, 1);
Insert into Result  (RundeID, PlayerID, Winder) values (2, 6, 0);
Insert into Result  (RundeID, PlayerID, Winder) values (2, 7, 0);
Insert into Result  (RundeID, PlayerID, Winder) values (2, 8, 0);


So far I got it this way:

Begin tran

UPDATE Players

SET NewPoint = Point * 1.10

FROM Result

INNER JOIN Players

ON Players.ID = Result.PlayerID

WHERE Winder = 1 AND RundeID = 1;

UPDATE Players

SET NewPoint = Point * 0.9

FROM Result

INNER JOIN Players

ON Player.ID = Result.PlayerID

WHERE Winder = 0 AND RundeID = 1

Now I need the math to be correct. Right now it just add 10 to the winder and deducts 10% from the loser. but If a game only has 1 winder he needs to get 10% from each loser (30%)
```

Comment: What's the question? You don't need an explicit transaction with single `UPDATE` or `INSERT` queries, they are atomic. And SQL Server is a *completely* different product from MySQL. Which one are you using?

Comment: An `UPDATE` query can have a `FROM` clause, which can include other tables, JOINs etc. Or, you can create correlated subqueries that somehow tie another table's rows to the current one, eg with `WHERE theOtherTable.ID=thisTable.OtherID`. Start by writing a SELECT that returns the results you want first.

Comment: I am using MSSQL